# Move Javascripts rendered by ASP.NET framework to end of body

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, performance

Does anyone know if it is possible to move script elements rendered automatically into a webforms output by ASP.NET down to the end of the body so they interfere less with page load times?

I'm talking about the likes of `__doPostBack` function and `/ScriptResource.axd` includes used by the AJAX framework etc.

Comment: Not that I know of. They probably don't have a big affect on page load times anyways. Sounds like premature optimization to me. By the way, if you want tighter control over your page markup, then Web Forms isn't a good choice. MVC with the Razor syntax would be much easier to control the markup.